# Editable URL with JavaScript window.open

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I open a window, the URL in the address bar is not editable:

```
window.open("http://localhost/", "_blank", 'top=100,left=100,width=800,height=600');
```

I need to change parameters in the URL, and the desired values are known to the user, but not to the code opening the window.  Is there a property or setting to make it editable?

Comment: This sounds an "XY-problem": What are you trying to achieve, what advantage does an editable address bar promise?

Comment: I need to change parameters in the URL after opening the window. Otherwise it's a usability issue. I would need to copy the URL, close the window, open a new window, paste the URL, change the paramters, then load the page. Much more mouse movement, clicking and key presses. So I need the URL to be editable. On a related note, can the window be opened in a maximized state?

Comment: `I need to change parameters in the URL`…and the desired value is known to the user, but not to the code opening the window? Please [put all information inviting useful answers in the question body](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)